# Limit How Much Text Gets Returned Django

Tags: django

I am getting data from my database and one of the fields could contain a large amount of text and I want to limit the amount of text it returns. Basically I am looking for the equivalent to PHP's `substr` function.

Right now I am grabbing the content from my database by

```
{{post.First_Name}} {{post.Last_Name}}
```

Is there a way I can limit the amount of text it returns from this field?
Thanks.

Comment: which version of django are you using? Also, how many characters do you want to limit the text to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to use `truncatewords` filter. You do it like so:

`{{ post.First_Name|truncatewords:3 }}`

You can gain even more precision if you want to. You can learn more about filters, and this one is particular [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords). You can gain even more fine-grain control with `truncatechars` if you so wish.